# dimen.xml or dimens.xml?

Tags: android, android-resources

I usually store dimensions in `dimen.xml` file. However, IntelliJ IDEA's intellisense places dimensions into file `dimens.xml`.

Now, what if I place dimensions into the file `dimens.xml`, how will Eclipse handle this?

I see that docs allow both files to be used. Which one **should be used** if the project will be used by **both** Eclipse and IDEA users?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It doesn't really matter what you name the file itself, however there are recommendations. From the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html) (on res/values):

> Because each resource is defined with its own XML element, you can
>   name the file whatever you want and place different resource types in
>   one file. However, for clarity, you might want to place unique
>   resource types in different files. For example, here are some **filename
>   conventions** for resources you can create in this directory:
>
> - arrays.xml for resource arrays (typed arrays).
> - colors.xml for color values
> - **dimens.xml for dimension values.**
> - strings.xml for string values.
> - styles.xml for styles.

Edit: For clarity, the important part is that you use the appropriate element (`<dimen>` in this case) inside a `<resource>` tag in your file. This is how android knows it's a dimension resource.

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="my_dimen">10dip</dimen>
</resources>
```

Comment: @Chaiavi: You'll have to ask the developers of your IDE. But don't worry about it, it doesn't matter what the filename is.

Comment: Also the google guidelines also have it as "dimen" https://developer.android.com/samples/BasicSyncAdapter/res/values/dimen.html
But I don't like it so I'm gonna name my file "dimens" since it doesn't matter :P